# sets and their compliments in a sigma algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $M(\mathbb R)$ be a sigma-algebra

$$A \in M \iff A^c = \mathbb R \backslash A \in M $$

why is this true

Comment: Do you know how one defines a sigma algebra?

Comment: yes. its a sigma ring and an algebra

Comment: @Seth that is not a definition unless you define sigma ring and algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\sigma$-algebra on any set $X$ is **by definition** closed under complements, so if $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then we have:$$A\in M\implies A^{\complement}\in M\tag1$$ so also:$$A^{\complement}\in M\implies\left(A^{\complement}\right)^{\complement}\in M\tag2$$
Now observe that $\left(A^{\complement}\right)^{\complement}=A$ so that $(2)$ can be rewritten as:$$A^{\complement}\in M\implies A\in M\tag3$$

Taking $(1)$ and $(3)$ together we find:$$A\in M\iff A^{\complement}\in M$$